# How to create this pattern in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create this GUI in Tkinter. I have created a 2x2 grid of buttons using a grid. I want Radio Buttons to span equal to the width of 2x2 buttons or buttons to span the width of radio buttons. Since we can't specify 1.5 (floats) as columns how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Lots of possible ways to achieve that, here's one: add two Frames to your window, `.pack()` them at top & bottom, then `.grid()` the four buttons into the top Frame and the three radio buttons into the bottom Frame.  Another possibility would be to use a 6-column grid - the buttons having columnspan=3, the radio buttons having columnspan=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities. Arguably the simplest would be to create a 6x3 grid. The buttons at the top each occupy 3 columns, the buttons along the bottom each take up two columns.